# In Universal analytics.js: how do you enable local remote server mode than sends data to your own server as well as to Google's?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, universal-analytics

I'm trying migrate website tracking from old Google Analytics script `ga.js` to new `analytics.js`.

Currently I have enabled "local remote server mode" to send tracing requests to my server as well. Following code was used to enable this mode on `ga.js`:

`_gaq.push(['_setLocalRemoteServerMode']);` ([more info](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiUrchin#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setLocalRemoteServerMode)).

But I can not find how to enable this feature on new [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/). Has anybody solved this already?

Comment: Are you still intending on using Urchin in conjunction with GA Universal?

Comment: I'll use anything what will allow send GA requests to my server too.

Comment: Not sure I follow that completely - the above is for [Urchin Software](https://www.google.com/urchin/faq.html). You can add other third-party tracking code to your pages, if that's what you meant. However, it doesn't appear that Universal supports Urchin (at least there's no reference to it anymore).

Comment: I've implemented by extending ga object, extracting data and sending requests to my server manually.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be an easy function built into analytics.js that I have found, however, there is this code for sending the same data via an XHR request to your server.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

ga(function(tracker) {

  // Grab a reference to the default sendHitTask function.
  var originalSendHitTask = tracker.get('sendHitTask');

  // Modifies sendHitTask to send a copy of the request to a local server after
  // sending the normal request to www.google-analytics.com/collect.
  tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) {
    originalSendHitTask(model);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/localhits', true);
    xhr.send(model.get('hitPayload'));
  });
});

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks